# Javascript alert how to achieve this

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, how to display alerts("any message for user") when something like this is executed:

```
window["any"]("message")("for")("user")
```

here window refers to the JavaScript global object.

Comment: "Executed"? Could you elaborate a little more? Is `window['any']` a function which returns a function which in returns yet another function?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @BradChristie and Juhana
I am also confused, What kind of questions I was asked.
The question was to write code that will display an alert box when the line of code as shown above was executed

I have never come across something like this beofore.

Answer (score 2):

Create function that returns function, and you will be able to call it as a(param)(param2)(param3)

```
window.any = function(m) {
   return function(f){
      return function(u) {
           alert(m + f + u);
       }

   }
}
```

the function can return itself so unlimited calls are possible, but you need to call it without param to actually show the message:

```
any = function(msg){

   var message = '';
   var chain = function(){
     if (arguments.length) {
        message += arguments[0] + ' ';
     } else {
        alert(message);
     }
     return chain;
   }
   return chain(msg);
}
```

usage:
`any("Message")("for")("user")();`

Edit:

```
var any = function(message) {
  var sentence = '', timeout = null;
  var f = function(msg){
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    if (sentence.length) {
      sentence += ' ';
    }

    sentence += msg;
    timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){window.alert(sentence);}, 100);
    return f;
  }
  return f(message);

 }
```

usage:
`any("Message")("for")("user");`

Comment: @Darhazar
can you please explain a bit
How can I use it to alert with for eg; "hello and welcome"
wher executing a line something like this
window["hello"]("and")("welcome");
I tried this but did not work

Comment: Thanks. It works now although with some modification to original question.